# is it possible to use a range variable from a linq (query syntax) as a parameter?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use a range variable from a linq query as a parameter;

something easy like;

```
private static Expression<Func<context.Table1, bool>> funstuff(context.Table2 data)
{
    return x => true;
}
```

using it like, another simple example, cross join;

```
var fun = from table2 in context.Table2
          from table1 in context.Table1.Where(funstuff(table2))
          select table1;

var f = fun.ToList();
```

and i'm getting this error;

> variable 'table2' of type 'context.Table2' referenced from scope '',
>   but it is not defined

is it possible to use a range variable as a parameter under entity framework 6?

**edit**

context is the dbcontext of entity framework

this exact code does work;

```
var fun = from table2 in context.Table2
          from table1 in context.Table1.Where(x => table2.Id == 1)
          select table1;

var f = fun.ToList();
```

and this doesn't work;

```
private static Expression<Func<context.Table1, bool>> funstuff(context.Table2 data)
{
    return x => data.Id == 1;
}



var fun = from table2 in context.Table2
          from table1 in context.Table1.Where(funstuff(table2))
          select table1;

var f = fun.ToList();
```

I was expecting that it would work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that your `context` is a `DbContext`.

Although most functions are similar, there is a difference between `Queryable` and `Enumerable`.

IEnumerable objects contain all code to enumerate over the objects in a collection which is in local memory. IEnumerable obects can use local functions while enumerating over them.

Queryable enumerations are meant to be performed on an other processor. An IQueryable object contains an expression that can be translated to a format that the other processor understands.

This translation is not in the `Expression`, but in another property of the `IQueryable`: the `Provider`. The `Provider` knows on which type machine the `Expression` is to be performed. Upon request the `Provider` will translate (compile) this expression into a format that this machine understands and will send the translation to this machine.

The object `context.Table2` implements `IQueryable`. The Provider in the `IQueryable` knows how to translate the query into SQL. SQL does not know any of your personal functions like `funstuff`, and thus the `Provider` does not know how to translate it into SQL. In fact, a DbSet does not even support all kinds of LINQ methods.

See [MSDN: Supported and Unsupported LINQ Methods (LINQ to Entities)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities)

So you can't call any of your local functions as long as your statements are IQueryable.

If it is really important to call the local functions you could perform them as `IEnumerable`. You do this with the function [AsEnumerable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335435%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396). This will bring the data that is input of the `AsEnumerable` to local memory. After that you can call all local functions as if your query was an `IEnumerable`

However there is a performance risk: If the input is thousends of objects and in the end you'll only end up with a few objects, it is a waste to bring all this information to local memory.

Conclusion: try to limit the data that is transferred to local memory to about the size you will need in your end result before calling `AsEnumerable`. After that you can call any local function you want.

Comment: see my edit for more (important) detail... I forgot to put it yesterday. is your answer still valid with that extra information?

Comment: "So you can't call any of your local functions as long as your statements are IQueryable." - that is not true. If `funstuff` in the question accepted no arguments or you pass constant argument there (like external `Error` instance) - EF provider will call it and will use returned `Expression`.

Comment: Are you sure? I can call Rnd.Next() in my query? Like DbSet.MyItems.Where(item => item.Id == rnd.Next()).ToList()? It gives me a NotSupportedException "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Random.Next() and this method cannot be translated into a store expression'

Comment: No I don't mean any methods in any places. But method like in question (one that returns expression and is passed to the "inner" `Where` clause) will be called by EF if possible. So for example `ctx.Table2.SelectMany(table2 => ctx.Table1.Where(funstuff()));`. Note that I don't mean methods which are invoked _before_ analyzing query. Method in OP will be called by EF analyzer _during_ query analyze.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do it this way. Consider Entity Framework analyzing your LINQ query to convert it to SQL query. It analyzes all the way down to `funstuff(table2)` call. It sees that it's a method call expression unknown to it (so not something like `SqlFunctions.GetDate()`). Ok, now EF analyzer needs to call this method to obtain expression. If method had no arguments or its arguments were known - no problem to call it. But this method argument represents query parameter `table2`. It does not have defined value when analyzing expression. It will only have a value (range of them) during SQL query execution. At that time, on SQL server, your method of course cannot be called with each value from that range. So query analyzer has absolutely no way to convert your query to SQL and fails.

Comment: see my edit for more (important) detail... I forgot to put it yesterday. is your answer still valid with that extra information?

Comment: @Fredou yes I assumed that this is Entity Framework DbContext (I actually start my answer with "Consider Entity Framework ..."), so information is still valid.